# Book recommendations for Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

I am seriously looking at adopting Umbraco to host several small business web `portals`. I have played with Umbraco some time ago, but I'd rather get a basic, exploratory prototype up and running with as much guidance as I can get, before getting down and dirty with my own coding.

A problem I have, however, is that I have found very little properly codified documentation for Umbraco, and very few resources outside of their forums etc.  Are there any good books available for Umbraco, or any other comprehensive resources I can preferably also use while offline?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe there's only one book - [Umbraco User's Guide](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470560827.html) by Nik Wahlberg & Paul Sterling (published by Wrox). You can find it on Amazon. I've glanced through it and it's probably good for beginners and intermediate users and does fill in a lot of the gaps in the [official documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki) (which you rightly note isn't comprehensive). As with all books it can lag a little behind latest versions, but it seems pretty up-to-date (as of Umbraco 4.7).

Another good resource are the official [Video Tutorials](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials) which cover most of the major topics. Some are a bit "amateur" but they do the job.

You'll also find plenty of good blogs and forum posts dotted around, so as usual Google is often your best friend. The Umbraco community are a friendly lot, so don't be afraid to ask questions on the [forum](http://our.umbraco.org/forum) etc.

Comment: The official documentation is not the wiki but has been moved to http://our.umbraco.org/documentation

Answer (score 4):

There is a handy online and PDF book: "[24 Days in Umbraco](http://24days.in/umbraco/2012/one-more-thing/)"